# NullReferenceException, no stack trace... where to start?

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, pinvoke, winmm

I have a WPF audio application.

Occasionally (and even in the debugger) I'm seeing a `NullReferenceException` which carries no stack trace information with it.

How can one start debugging such an issue?

Some background:

I'm P/Invoking functions in `WinMM.dll` which involves registering a [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743869%28VS.85%29.aspx) when calling `waveOutOpen`

```
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern MmResult waveOutOpen(out IntPtr phwo, IntPtr uDeviceID, WaveFmt pwfx, WaveCallbk dwCallback, IntPtr dwInstance, int fdwOpen);
```

This has proved difficult to get stable, especially at the point where I call `waveOutClose`, and immediately call `waveOutOpen` again (usually to change the output format).

I suspect that the problem may be related to the calls I've been describing above (although on so little knowlege, I could be completely off-target).

Reproducing the problem is currently proving elusive, although I can supply a build to a user who is fairly consistently seeing this problem. I might try to speed up the operations that are causing the problem to the point where reproducing the problem in the debugger is more of a certainty.

With regards to the debugger, I haven't tinkered with any of the settings (including `Enable unmanaged code debugging`) or any of the `Debug -> Exceptions...` settings. To be honest, I'm fairly clueless about what's on offer here, so any hints are welcome.

How might an exception not have a stack trace? Have you seen this before? Help!

Comment: Yes, this sort of thing happens all to often when working with unmanaged code. And it it a total PITA. Personally I would love to have a checklist of things to go through.

Comment: A checklist would be awesomely handy. Anyone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most helpful thing you can do in the debugger is instruct it to break on a first-chance exception (Debug -> Exceptions):

[image: VS Exceptions window]

This will cause a break into the debugger at the exact point a `NullReferenceException` is thrown, which is pretty much the best you can ever hope for while debugging.

Comment: Good. Just got to make it happen in the debugger... ger... grrrr.

Comment: Many thanks! This has moved in VS 2015 in case you are wondering.. Debug->Windows->Exception Setting. There it has a search, so probably easiest to use search box for NullReference.