# Can Exception stack trace ever be null?

Tags: c#, exception

I found out that if I am catching an Exception e, e.innerException could possibly be null.

Is it also possible that e.StackTrace could also be null in any possible circumstance in a catch block?

```
try {

}
catch(Exception e)
{
//can e.StackTrace be null here?
}
```

Comment: I would say yes:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620678/nullreferenceexception-no-stack-trace-where-to-start

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783561/nullreferenceexception-with-no-stack-trace-when-hooking-setconsolectrlhandler

Answer (score 18):

Yes.

If you create a `new Exception()` and don't throw it, every property except `Data` and `Message` will be null.

Comment: I think more importantly, if you do not code exceptions properly, [then all sorts of debug information may go missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/throwing-exceptions-best-practices).

Comment: What if it's in a catch block?

Comment: @Servy: Wrong.  (try it)

Comment: @HenleyChiu: It can be empty, but I don't think it can be null.

Answer (score 4):

An example that proves the `StackTrace` can be null in a catch block is equally trivial to show:

```
public class DerpException : Exception
{
    public override string StackTrace
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually shocked that `StackTrace` is virtual, simply because derived classes *shouldn't* be able to do something like this.

Comment: Looking in dotPeek, the property is actually defined in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices._Exception` interface, which explains why it's virtual in the base `System.Exception` class - the reasons for this interface are out of my reach as a lowly purveyor of purely managed code though.

Comment: The `Exception` class could still mark it as `sealed`, preventing *further* overrides of that property.

Comment: Sealing `Exception` would prevent *any* kind of more specific exception class from existing though.

Inheriting the field from an interface doesn't force it to be implemented as `virtual` in the base `Exception` class either though, it just has to be `public`; I was brain dead at that point yesterday.

Comment: You can seal that property (or a method) without sealing the whole class.  That's what I suggested.

Comment: I misread initially, but you don't even need to do that since methods aren't virtual by default in C#, you just need to *not* have the method be marked virtual, which is back to the original point. It seems like a deliberate design decision, and a really odd one.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get `exception.StackTrace` as a null, if you use 
`[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` attribute for your function with try-catch, where you catch exception, and if exception is thrown from native code.

`System.AccessViolationException` exception type might have `StackTrace` as null.

Not sure if this has anything to do with Debug/Release build and/or generated pdb files.
I've observes this kind of crash for Release build.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a case where the exception had a `Message`, but the mere *access* of `StackTrace` threw an exception!

This worth repeating: Just *accessing* the `StackTrace` threw an exception, i.e. without even calling a method upon it (like `ex.StackTrace.ToString()`).

This happened when working with COM libraries.

Specifically, it happened when a .NET Framework dll referenced an [interop dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670940/what-is-the-interop-dll). For some reason the clr couldn't find and load that interop dll, and the exception thrown was a normal `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, which had a `Message`.

*But*, accessing its `StackTrace` *itself* threw an exception with the following stack trace:

```
System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)\r\n   at
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()\r\n   at  
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()\r\n   at   
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)\r\n   at   
System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)\r\n   at  
System.Exception.GetStackTrace(Boolean needFileInfo)\r\n   at  
System.Exception.get_StackTrace()
```